# Content of a webpage where the url is in another file

Tags: php

That's may be a stupid question but after some search, I did not find the answer.

I want to read the content of a webpage with get_file content where the url of the page is read from another file (test.txt)

```
<?php
$url= file_get_contents('test.txt');
//$url= 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php';
$content= file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

If I use the url from file_get_contents('test.txt'), it does not work but if I write it explicitely ($url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php';), it works.

The content of test.txt is -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php -- there is no more

Both variables are strings so I do not understand why reading the file, putting the content in a variable does not work.

Where is the problem ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `var_dump($url);` shows what exactly? Likely a problem with either a byte order mark or some white space or sth.

Comment: Provide the values for `var_dump($url)` and `var_dump($content)`. Also: The file thats being executed is in the same folder as test.txt? The script has enough rights to read the file?

Comment: @CBroe 
Indeed var_dump($url); is 47 for the url in the and 46
I corrected it by extracting a substring with a length strlen($url)-1

Maybe not very nice but it works

Answer (score 0):

try doing it this way

```
$url= file_get_contents('http://localhost/mywebsite/test.txt');
$content= file_get_contents($url);
echo $content;
```